# easier way to evaluate Integrals of complicated rational functions

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

For integrals such as these:
$$\int \frac{dx}{x^5(x+1)}, \int \frac{x^8dx}{x^3+x^2+2}, \int \frac{x^6dx}{x^4 + x^3 + 5x + 1}$$
Do easy methods/algorithms exist to evaluate them?

One method is to divide the numerator by the denominator. Another is to use partial fractions. Both of these are quite tedious and hard to do by hand. Are there other ways of doing these that I am missing?

Comment: Aside from some special cases, partial fractions decomposition is the only way I am aware of

Comment: If those integral were definite integrals with "nice" bounds you could try to use contour integration

Comment: Infinite series of the integrand (when you can !)